# How to distinguish data sent from two pages in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Suppose consider i'm sending a data from page 1 as shown below,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2?id=" + id, UriKind.Relative));
```

And also if i send another data from page3 to again page2 as below,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2?data=" + data, UriKind.Relative));
```

How can i distinguish both the data, and also i want if i could determine to which function the control should go??
If so please do tell me the way or suggest me a document on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Query strings parameters

```
 private bool HasData
    {
        get
        {
            return NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("data");
        }
    }

    private bool HasId
    {
        get
        {
            return NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id");
        }
    }

     private string ReadValue(string key)
    {
        return NavigationContext.QueryString[key];
    }
```

Read the values

```
private void DoAction()
  {

      if (HasData)
      {
          var data = this.ReadValue("data");
      }
      else if (HasId)
      {
          var id = this.ReadValue("id");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we determine, to which function the control sholud go?? i.e i need to continue the flow///

Answer (score 0):

Well don't make your live hard use simple condition. what i mean is

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("id"))
    {
        var ID = NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];          
        //this is a parameter from page1 
        // do something
    }
    else   if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("data"))
    {
        var data = NavigationContext.QueryString["data"];          
        //this is a parameter from page2 
        // do something
    }
}
```

that's it (: